# PDO Prepare statement not processing parameters

Tags: php, mysql, singleton, pdo

I've exhausted all efforts at what appears to be a trivial problem, but gotten nowhere.

There is a simple Prepare statement:

```
$qry = $core->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '?'");
$qry->execute(array('email@address.com'));
```

However, no rows are returned. Running the query with the parameters hardcoded into the query results in a successful selection of one row. I've tryed many different methods of doing the prepare, but even it this most simple form it isn't working.

The PDO object is stored in a singleton called Core. PDO is using the mysql driver.

Comment: Could you post the code showing how you fetch the results?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove quotes from the query:

```
("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?");
```

The reason to use placeholders (`?` symbol) is to forget about quotes. PDO will add them automatically.

Comment: Oh god, I didn't even notice that. This was more of a brainteaser. +1

Comment: *sigh* I must have tryed everything except this. Thanks :)