# Using named parameters with PDO for LIKE

Tags: php, sql, search, pdo

I am trying to search the `name` field in my database using `LIKE`. If I craft the SQL 'by hand` like this:

```
$query = "SELECT * \n"
        . "FROM `help_article` \n"
        . "WHERE `name` LIKE '%how%'\n"
        . "";
$sql = $db->prepare($query);
$sql->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$sql->execute();
```

Then it will return relevant results for 'how'.
However, when I turn it into a prepared statement:

```
$query = "SELECT * \n"
        . "FROM `help_article` \n"
        . "WHERE `name` LIKE '%:term%'\n"
        . "";
$sql->execute(array(":term" => $_GET["search"]));
$sql->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$sql->execute();
```

I am always getting zero results.

What am I doing wrong? I am using prepared statements in other places in my code and they work fine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PDO Prepare statement not processing parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434560/pdo-prepare-statement-not-processing-parameters)

Answer (score 40):

The bound `:placeholders` are not to be enclosed in single quotes. That way they won't get interpreted, but treated as raw strings.

When you want to use one as `LIKE` pattern, then pass the `%` together with the value:

```
$query = "SELECT * 
          FROM `help_article` 
          WHERE `name` LIKE :term ";

$sql->execute(array(":term" => "%" . $_GET["search"] . "%"));
```

Oh, and actually you need to clean the input string here first (addcslashes). If the user supplies any extraneous `%` chars within the parameter, then they become part of the LIKE match pattern. Remember that the whole of the `:term` parameter is passed as string value, and all `%`s within that string become placeholders for the LIKE clause.

Comment: [Escaping in standard SQL](http://drupal.org/node/654662) isn't as simple as that. in PL/SQL and Transact SQL, for example, you have to supply the character to be used as an escape character.

Comment: @jswolf19: Wasn't even sure about escaping in MySQL, and I usually rather strip any non-alphanumeric characters. (Might be sufficient for OP too.)

Comment: I think MySQL does default to `\ `, but OP doesn't specify a DB, and standard SQL doesn't specify a default escape character. You have to supply it with the `a LIKE b ESCAPE c` syntax.