# PHP / PDO search with pattern matching

Tags: php, search, pdo, match

when i search for a user in database, i do:

```
$result = $dbh->query("SELECT user FROM table_user WHERE user = '".$user."' ");
    $result->execute();
    while ($user = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $array[] = $user['user'];
    }
```

But i first get a result, when

```
user
```

and

```
$user
```

are exactly the same.

But i already need a result, when "$user" is part of "user", anybody knows how to do such a pattern matching?

Greetings!!

Comment: have you heard of SQL operator "LIKE"?

Comment: Your question is not clear for me. Also, when using PDO:query no need to execute, because: `PDO::query — Executes an SQL statement, returning a result set as a PDOStatement object`

Comment: for what you use pdo? `'".$user."'` is very bad practice...

Comment: use placeholder´s instead or what u mean vp_arth ?

Comment: "here's a dollar. gimme a dollar. hey! why is this the same dollar!?"

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7252283/using-named-paramaters-with-pdo-for-like?rq=1), @user3297073.

Answer (score 1):

You are searching for the [`LIKE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-comparison-functions.html) statement. Further note that when you interpolate $user this way you are vulnerable against SQL injections. You should use a prepared statement-

Use this:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT user FROM table_user WHERE user LIKE :search");
$stmt->execute(array('user' => "%$user%"));

while($user = $stmt->fetch()) {
    var_dump($user);
}
```