# Symfony SQL Injection

Tags: php, symfony, sql-injection

Hi everyone !
I'm currently fixing a bug in an application, and there's this code that I have a question about.

```
$query = $this->em->createQuery(
            "SELECT client FROM App\\Entity\\Gescom\\Client client WHERE client.name LIKE CONCAT('%', :query, '%')"
        )
            ->setFirstResult(($request->get('page') - 1) * $request->get('page_limit'))
            ->setMaxResults($request->get('page_limit'));
        $query->execute([
            'query' => $request->get('q') . '%'
        ]);
```

Regarding this line:

```
$query->execute([
            'query' => $request->get('q') . '%'
        ]);
```

Are there any SQL injection issues or is it safe?

I've searched online, but I can't find an answer to my question. Does `execute()` protect against all SQL injections even when I concatenate something within it?

Comment: The code is using the method from https://stackoverflow.com/a/7252344/3783243 The `. '%'` is redundant in the binding (execute) as your concatenation already does that. `CONCAT('%', :query, '%')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you pass into `execute()` is a list of parameter names and their values, which the database engine then puts into the SQL statement safely in place of the matching named placeholders (marked with `:` in your SQL statement).

So in this case you're actually not concatenating anything into your SQL, you're correctly providing a separate SQL statement and list of parameter values. The database engine will ensure that the parameterised values are never treated as snippets of executable SQL.

Therefore, yes, it should be safe from SQL injection.