# Having an issue binding parameters to a PDO Statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am having a strange issue that I am just not finding a solution to.  The problem is that the prepared sql statement is not binding in values, parameters or even passing them through the execute function.  Instead, it inserts the ':blah' placeholder.  As I said, I have tried bindParam, bindValue and this method all without result.  However, I will try them all again now.

I outputted the parameters being sent right before the execute call.

```
Array ( [:username] => schenn [:salt] => NW5552wekj5155cNr52O54q56 [:hashpass] => 5e54240aec6294873d11d6ac3e5b135136a1b671 [:email] => monkey@monkey.com [:state] => OR [:country] => USA [:last_login] => 12/08/2011 )
```

Below is the code:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO player_acct (username, salt, hashpass, email, state, country, last_login)
                VALUES (':username', ':salt', ':hashpass', ':email', ':state', ':country', ':last_login')";
$stmt = $pdoI->prepare($query);
$params = array(":username" => $this->username, ":salt" => $this->salt, ":hashpass" => $this->hashpass,
                        ":email" => $this->email, ":state" => $this->state, ":country" => $this->country, ":last_login" => $this->last_login );
$stmt->execute($params);
```

Comment: the printout from the errorinfo for both the pdo and the statment are

Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => )

Comment: They are sent in from a post or generated then loaded into the object.  The object is handed the pdo which it then uses in conjunction with it properties.   The array above is the information being stored in the params array.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PDO Prepare statement not processing parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434560/pdo-prepare-statement-not-processing-parameters)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldnt be quoting the placeholders in the SQL. Try the following as your SQL string:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO player_acct (username, salt, hashpass, email, state, country,  
          last_login) VALUES (:username, :salt, :hashpass, :email, :state, :country, :last_login)";
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't quote the binded values in the SQL statement when binding variables.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO player_acct (username, salt, hashpass, email, state, country, last_login) VALUES (:username, :salt, :hashpass, :email, :state, :country, :last_login)";
```

Also make sure `$this->email`, etc... is set correctly.