# PHP: PDO bindValue() causes 0 results to be returned

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, bindvalue

I've having some troubles with the PDO bindValue() function. Whenever I seem to use it, my queries always return 0 results. However it works fine if I put $user and $pass straight into the sql without the use of bindValue()

$user is a string
$password is a sha1() hash

```
public function login($user, $pass) {
            global $CMS;

            $sql = "SELECT `username,`password` FROM `" . TB_PREFIX . "users` WHERE `username` = ':user' AND `password` = ':pass'";
            $query = $CMS->prepare_query($sql);
            $query->bindValue(':user', $user, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query->bindValue(':pass', $pass, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query->execute();

            # User successfully authenticated
            if ($query->rowCount() == 1) {
                # Get all data from DB and populate class variables
                self::populate_user_data($user);
                session_register($user . "-" . base64_encode($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']));
                return true;
            }

            # User failed authentication            
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: `':user'` - why not just `:user`? Read the manual, it has *examples*: [`bindyValue`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php).

Comment: Try to print $query before you execute() it.

Comment: And also check the syntax, it's broken (apart from the placeholders). So be more careful next time.

Comment: Reading [php PDOStatement->bindValue doc](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php) it seems that problem are quotes. You should write: WHERE `username` = :user insteat WHERE `username` = ':user'

Comment: possible duplicate of [PDO Prepare statement not processing parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434560/), [Having an issue binding parameters to a PDO Statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8436963/), [Using named paramaters with PDO for LIKE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7252283/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not put the quotes around the values yourself, they will be added (if needed, such as in the case of strings - this case):

```
$sql = "SELECT `username,`password` FROM `" . TB_PREFIX . "users` 
        WHERE `username` = :user AND `password` = :pass";
```

Answer (score 1):

The placeholders in a prepared statement must not be quoted; PDO is already doing all the quoting. You want:

```
 $sql = "SELECT `username,`password` FROM `" . TB_PREFIX . "users` " .
        "WHERE `username` = :user AND `password` = :pass";
```

Answer (score 1):

When using prepared statements, the values get escaped automagically.

This means, that you don't have to set quotes around the arguments.

try:

```
$sql = "SELECT `username,`password` ".
       "FROM `" . TB_PREFIX . "users` ".
       "WHERE `username` = :user AND `password` = :pass";
```

and you should be fine.

As a side note though: you should *NEVER* store user passwords literally. Check this excellent article: [You're Probably Storing Passwords Incorrectly](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/09/youre-probably-storing-passwords-incorrectly.html)